# copy bindinglist to another one

Tags: c#, class, bindinglist

```
public class MyBindingList : BindingList<int>
        {
            public MyBindingList()
            {
            }
            private BindingList<int> temp;
            public void Backup()
            {
                int[] arr = new int[this.Count];
                this.CopyTo(arr,0);
                temp = new BindingList<int>(arr);
            }
            public void Restore()
            {
                this.Items.Clear();
                //for(int i=0;i<temp.Count;i++) this.Add(temp[i]);
            }
        }
```

`//for(int i=0;i<temp.Count;i++) this.Add(temp[i]);`

is a so slowly way to restore, so what can i use for more efficiently restore()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your example, foreach is the easiest and quickest way.

The faster way is via a copy-contructor.  However with your example, it won't work.  You can't say this = new ...

```
myList = new BindingList<int>(temp);
```

---

Edit: Side-comment, you can clean up Backup() by deleting the creation of the array and just call:

```
public void Backup()
{
    this.temp = new BindingList<int>(this);
}
```